# java osx application won't start

Tags: java, macos, deployment, jar

I'm trying to package a Java application for OSX.  There's an older version that I created six months ago that works fine.  It's all in a directory named Intonia.app, with the jar file in `Intonia.app/Contents/Resources/Java`.  I can click on the app in the Finder, and my code runs just fine.

Now I've got an updated version that refuses to run.  When I double-click the app, the application icon appears briefly in the dock, and disappears.  The Console application show a message, `"com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.intonia.tony.Intonia.60048[531]) Exited with code 1."`  Yet when I view the package contents in the Finder and doubleclick the Intonia.jar icon, my app runs OK.

I can swap the old and the new jar files in the app directory, leaving all the other files in the directory the same.  The old jar file runs both as an app and by double-clicking the .jar file.  The new file does not run as an app, but double-clicking the .jar file works.

Both the old jar and the new jar have the identically-named `com.intonia.tony.Intonia.main()` as the entry point.  The old version had all classes in a package named com.intonia.tony.  The new version divides the classes between `com.intonia.tony` and `com.intonia.common`.

Please feel free to direct me to another forum if there's a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Not sure if will help, but you could look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/194094/how-do-i-get-rid-of-com-apple-launchd-peruser-errors-in-my-log) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/686922/causes-of-com-apple-launchd-peruser-501-exited-with-code-1) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/361475/com-apple-launchd-com-apple-launchd-peruser-error).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the old jar file was compiled in Eclipse with Compiler compliance level of 1.5, and the new file was compiled with 1.7.  I recompiled with level 1.5, and it worked.

At this point my immediate problem is solved.  I'll leave it to others to figure out why the app launcher can't deal with it, or why the message I got was so opaque.